# ListView item won't extend width to fill_parent

Tags: android, android-layout, android-listview, width, listviewitem

I have a custom `ViewGroup` that inflates a `ListView` from an `xml` layout. The list item layout is inflated from another `xml` file. All of the views are set to `fill_parent`. The `ListView` fills its parent, but the `ListView` items don't.

I've tried putting the `ListView` in a `LinearLayout` and assigning weight to it. Tried `RelativeLayout` as well. Also, I've built the `ListView` programmaticaly, without using the `xml` layout. Even changed the `LayoutParams` before adding the view to the `ViewGroup`.

I've also taken in consideration these posts as well: [Width of clickable area in ListView w/ onListItemClick](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6497000/935627), [In Android, how can I set a ListView item's height and width?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3210337/935627), [Android Listview width prob](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8064416/935627).

Any ideas to why the items don't extend to fill width? And how to extend them?

**MyViewGroup class:**

```
public class MyViewGroup extends ViewGroup {

    public MyViewGroup(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
        generateMyViewGroup();

    }

    private void generateMyViewGroup()
    {
        ListView main = (ListView) View.inflate(getContext(), R.layout.layout_main, null);

        main.setAdapter(new MyAdapter(getContext()));

        this.addView(main);     
    }

    @Override
    protected void onLayout(boolean changed, int l, int t, int r, int b) {
        this.getChildAt(0).layout(l, t, r, b);
    }
}
```

**`ListView` `xml` layout:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ListView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@android:id/list"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginRight="3dp"
    android:background="#77000000"
    android:cacheColorHint="#00000000"
    android:divider="#00000000"
    android:dividerHeight="0dp"
    android:drawSelectorOnTop="false"
    android:scrollbars="vertical" >
</ListView>
```

**`ListView` item layout:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/layout_main_category"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@color/mainBackground"
    android:gravity="fill_horizontal|center_vertical"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/main_category"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
        android:paddingBottom="7dp"
        android:paddingLeft="20dp"
        android:paddingRight="5dp"
        android:paddingTop="20dp"
        android:text="test"
        android:textColor="@color/mainCategory"
        android:textSize="15sp"
        android:textStyle="bold" />

</LinearLayout>
```

**Part of `MyAddapter` class:**

```
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    ViewHolder viewHolder;

    if(null == convertView)
    {
        LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
        convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.layout_main_category, null);

        viewHolder = new ViewHolder();

        viewHolder.mainItemTitle = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.main_category);

        convertView.setTag(viewHolder);
    } else {
        viewHolder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag(); 
    }

    viewHolder.mainItemTitle.setText("text");

    return convertView;
}

private static class ViewHolder {
        public TextView menuItemTitle;
}
```

Comment: add the items view  inflating code also

Comment: @TomerMor I've added the `getView()` function of the custom `BaseAdapter` I'm using.

Comment: What is the use of MyViewgroup ?

Comment: @userSeven7s I'm using the view in different activities.

Comment: why do you override the onLayout? anyways call super.onLayout..

Comment: `super.onLayout()` is not accepted by `ViewGroup`. And if I don't overwrite `onLayout()` it won't draw anything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `ViewGroup` didn't end up working properly. I've also tried to use `LinearLayout`. But `RelativeLayout` ended up properly inflating the layout. So, my `xml` layouts and the adapter stayed unchanged, but I changed the main class to extend `RelativeLayout`. Also removed the `onLayout()`.

**MyView class:**

```
public class MyView extends RelativeLayout {
    //Extra code unchanged ....

    private void generateMyView()
    {
        ListView menu = (ListView) View.inflate(getContext(), R.layout.layout_main, null);

        menu.setAdapter(new MyAdapter(getContext()));

        this.addView(menu);
    }

    //Removed onLayout()
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you override the `onLayout`, you should override the `onMeasure` as well.. almost always..

```
@Override 
protected void onMeasure(int widthMeasureSpec, int heightMeasureSpec){
   int parentWidth = MeasureSpec.getSize(widthMeasureSpec);
   int parentHeight = MeasureSpec.getSize(heightMeasureSpec);
   this.setMeasuredDimension(parentWidth, parentHeight);
   // this.setLayoutParams(new 
          //   *ParentLayoutType*.LayoutParams(parentWidth,parentHeight));
   super.onMeasure(widthMeasureSpec, heightMeasureSpec);
}
```

If it still doesn't work, use the commented line too..

### Update:

Another option for you is to forget `onLayout` and `onMeasure`, and override `onFinishInflate()` and add these lines to it. If you are inflating `MyViewGroup` from xml.

```
protected void onFinishInflate () {
    super.onFinishInflate();
    ListView main = (ListView) View.inflate(getContext(), 
                                    R.layout.layout_main,null);
    main.setAdapter(new MyAdapter(getContext()));
    this.addView(main); 
}
```

Comment: The `ListView` shows. I can see its background. But none of the items show anymore. I've tried all 3 of your options.

Comment: I've ended up changing the `ViewGroup` to `RelativeLayout`.